# Get 2 columns of table in a relationship

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following Entity Framework 7 entities:

```
public class EbookFile {    
  public Int32 EbookId { get; set; }
  public Int32 FileId { get; set; }
  public virtual Ebook Ebook { get; set; }
  public virtual File File { get; set; }
}

public class File {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public Byte[] Content { get; set; }  
  public String Name { get; set; }    
  public virtual ICollection<EbookFile> EbooksFiles { get; set; }
}
```

Given an EbookId I need to get Ids and Names of all files associated with it:

```
Dictionary<Int32, Dictionary<String, Int32>> files = await _context
  .EbooksFiles
  .Include(x => x.File)
  .Where(x => result.Select(y => y.Id).Contains(x.EbookId))
  .GroupBy(x => x.EbookId)
  .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.Key, x => x.ToDictionary(y => y.File.Name, y => y.File.Id));
```

The problem is that I am also getting the Content which I do not want:

```
SELECT [x].[EbookId], [x].[FileId], [f].[Id], [f].[Content], [f].[Name]
FROM [EbooksFiles] AS [x]
INNER JOIN [Files] AS [f] ON [x].[FileId] = [f].[Id]
```

How can I improve my Linq expression to get only the FileId and Name into a dictionary?

**TEST QUERY**

```
var ids = new Int32[] { 1, 2 };

var files = _context
    .EbooksFiles
    .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.EbookId))
    .Select(x => new { x.EbookId, x.File.Name, x.File.Id })
    .GroupBy(x => x.EbookId)
    .ToList();
```

**STACK TRACE**

2016-04-29 15:13:40 [Error] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.<>c__DisplayClass79_0`1.b__0(IEnumerable`1 ps, IQuerySource qs)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.BindMemberExpressionCore[TResult](MemberExpression memberExpression, IQuerySource querySource, Func`3 memberBinder)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.BindMemberExpression[TResult](MemberExpression memberExpression, IQuerySource querySource, Func`3 memberBinder)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.BindMemberExpression(MemberExpression memberExpression, Action`2 memberBinder)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.RequiresMaterializationExpressionVisitor.VisitMember(MemberExpression memberExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.ExpressionVisitorBase.Visit(Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitAndConvert[T](ReadOnlyCollection`1 nodes, String callerName)
   at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.RelinqExpressionVisitor.VisitNew(NewExpression expression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.NewExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.ExpressionVisitorBase.Visit(Expression expression)
   at Remotion.Linq.Clauses.ResultOperators.GroupResultOperator.TransformExpressions(Func`2 transformation)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryModel.TransformExpressions(Func`2 transformation)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.RequiresMaterializationExpressionVisitor.FindQuerySourcesRequiringMaterialization(QueryModel queryModel)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.QueryCompilationContext.FindQuerySourcesRequiringMaterialization(EntityQueryModelVisitor queryModelVisitor, QueryModel queryModel)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass18_0`1.b__0()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at EbookGetApiModelHandler.QueryHandler.<Handle>d__4.MoveNext() in \Handlers\EbookGetApiModelHandler.cs:line 85
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MediatR.Mediator.<SendAsync>d__4`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Controllers.EbookApiController.<Get>d__2.MoveNext() in \Controllers\EbookApiController.cs:line 30
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionExecutor.<CastToObject>d__8`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionInvoker.d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.d__53.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.d__44.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Infrastructure.MvcRouteHandler.d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Routing.InnerAttributeRoute.d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.RouteCollection.d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot `.Include(x => x.File)` in your test query